# how to run sml/nj program under emacs

Tags: smlnj, emacs24

after one day struggle I finally configure Emacs for SML/NJ. 
I am new to both emacs and SML, now I am having problem  to how to run sml program under emacs.
when I command,
M-x sml-mode
it looks OK, no error report.

and after open(or create file like test.sml), I write simple sml program and I don't know how to compile it. I tried C-c C-c and C-c C-b as showed in some video. but there is no any response. 
I am using emacs 24.1, SMLNj and windows vista system. 
could some on tell me how compile and run SML program in emacs? I am beginner, so simple and detailed answer .

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try `C-c C-l` instead. You're going to have to fiddle about and make sure that whatever `sml` executable you have is available to Emacs and in your PATH or whatever. I'm not familiar enough with Emacs on Windows to help you there. But here's the relevant section of the `sml-mode` manual: http://www.smlnj.org/doc/Emacs/sml-mode.html#Interaction-Mode

Answer (score 1):

I use this piece of code to start and restart sml repl. I bind it to M-s M-m.

```
(defun isml ()
  "If sml repl exists, then restart it else create a new repl"
  (interactive)
  (when (get-buffer "*sml*")
    (with-current-buffer "*sml*"
      (when (process-live-p "sml")
        (comint-send-eof)))
    (sleep-for 0.2))
  (sml-run "sml" ""))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-s M-m") 'isml)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun gcr/sml-eval-buffer ()
  "Intelligently evaluate a SML buffer."
  (interactive)
  (gcr/save-all-file-buffers)
  (let ((sml-process (get-process "sml")))
    (when sml-process
      (quit-process sml-process)))
  (sleep-for 0.25)
  (let ((sml-buffer (get-buffer "*sml*")))
    (when sml-buffer
      (kill-buffer sml-buffer)))
  (sml-prog-proc-load-file buffer-file-name))
```

Answer (score 0):

@wenjun.yan 's answer does not work on my Emacs. So I changed that to this:

```
(defun isml ()
 "If sml repl exists, then restart it else create a new repl"
 (interactive)
 (when (get-buffer "*sml*")
   (when (process-live-p
   (get-process "sml"))
     (with-current-buffer "*sml*"
(comint-send-eof)))
   (sleep-for 0.2)
   (kill-buffer "*sml*"))
 (sml-run "sml" ""))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 'isml)
```